# Cant push to queue with underlying list

Tags: c++, list, graph, queue, pass-by-reference

Following an [example from my professor](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/sum16/Public/graphtraverse/index.html), using a list-based queue to traverse a graph:

```
void breadthFirst (Point* root)
{
   queue<list<Point*> > q;
   q.push (root);
 }

error: no matching function for call to ‘std::queue<std::list<Point*> >::push(Point*&)’
    q.push (root);
```

Similarly:

```
void breadthFirstTraversal (const Point& start)
{
  queue<list<Point> > q;
  q.push (start); 
}      

error: no matching function for call to ‘std::queue<std::list<Point> >::push(const Point&)’
   q.push (start);
```

I've reviewed materials on pointers and references and tried different ways of passing the vars.

Based on the documentation, it appears that the constructor may be incorrect `std::queue<int,std::list<int>`

Comment: Do you really want a queue of lists of Points or just a queue of Points?

Comment: @aichao: that is what I thought too, but his professor's code does exactly that. I don't know if his professor ever tested that code, though.

Comment: It is quite unfortunate. I don't expect much from academic code, but I do think it's in the student's best interest to be given functional, sensible code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at reliable documentation:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class queue;
```

we see that the `std::queue` needs to be defined as

```
std::queue<type of element, type of container to base queue on> nameOfQueue;
```

There are two ways to go with this:

```
queue<Point, list> q;
```

To specify a `queue` of `Point`s where the container used by the `queue` to store `Point`s is a `list`.

or

```
 queue<list<Point>>
```

where we have a `queue` that contains `list`s of `Point`s. I'm ignoring pointers for now because they are just a distraction.

OP and their instructor's code does not make which variant to use clear. As OP has found, one cannot push `Point` into a `queue<list<Point>>` because `Point` is not a `list<Point>`.

Let's stop and look at the example provided to OP:

```
void breadthFirst (TreeNode* root)
{
   queue<list<TreeNode*> > q;
   q.push (root); // impossible. root is not list<TreeNode*>
   while (!q.empty())
     {
      v = q.front (); // type of v not specified. Based on usage, assuming TreeNode *
      q.pop ();
      for (int i = 0; i < v->numChildren(); ++i)
        {
         TreeNode* w = v->child[i];
         if (w != 0)
           q.push (w);
        }
     }
}
```

I can see where the instructor got their head twisted on backwards. I think they wanted

```
void breadthFirst(std::list<std::list<std::list<...>*>*>* root)
```

That ... represents an infinite template recursion. Good luck with that. The instructor wisely avoided falling down this rabbit hole.

Abstracting this mess with a structure

```
struct TreeNode
{
    std::list <TreeNode* > children;
};
```

is the right idea. The instructor just needed to carry it through.

Now we can define

```
std::queue<TreeNode*> q;
```

and

```
q.push(root);
```

Trying to clean this up, based on a pre-existing understanding of tree traversal and modern C++ (and it would suck to not have pre-existing knowledge given an example like this), we get something like

```
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

void breadthFirst(TreeNode* root)
{
    std::queue<TreeNode*> q;
    q.push(root);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        TreeNode*v = q.front();
        q.pop();

        std::cout << v->name; // added to visually demonstrate. Do stuff here

        for (TreeNode * w: v->children) // visit all children in order
        {
            // no need to check for nulls. list doesn't need to contain empty slots
            // this was likely a left over from a previous C implementation
            q.push(w);
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

A quick tester:

```
int main()
{
    TreeNode A('A');
    TreeNode B('B');
    TreeNode C('C');
    TreeNode D('D');
    TreeNode E('E');

    A.children.push_back(&B);
    A.children.push_back(&D);
    B.children.push_back(&E);
    E.children.push_back(&C);

    breadthFirst(&A);
}
```

five nodes A contains B and D. B contains C. C contains E.

```
 A
B D
C
E
```

In breadth first, traversal visits root, then all of root's children in order, then the children of the children in order, so

```
ABDCE
```

Side note: depending on how you are running this, `std::list` may not be the best container to use here given the ability of modern processors to predict and cache. With, say, a std::vector, the processor always knows which is the next element to be visited and where to look for it, so the CPU can preload the next or next few items when it reads the first. With a list the items are typically scrambled, making the CPU bounce around through memory, reading a bit here and a bit there and never really get a chance to get ahead of itself.

Comment: I was able to compile using `queue<Point,list<Point> > q;`. This class focuses on std datatypes and algorithm analysis; I believe there is an O advantage to using a list instead of a deque in this queue.

Comment: Two things. 1. You can compile that way, but the algorithm won't work. 2. Ignoring practical computing and sticking to the theoretical, `list` gives you O(1) insert and delete, but utterly murders, O(N), you in traversal. On the plus side, for this case you always traverse O(N). `list` wins! But when you step away back into practical programming and profile the running code you'll see that a lot of the time `list` will lose because of all the time wasted waiting for RAM access. It's like O(1) is kinda useless if that 1 takes 14.5 billion years.